# Bash turning single comma-separated column into multi-line string

Tags: bash, awk, sed, multiple-columns

In my input file, columns are tab-separated, and the values inside each column are comma-separated.

I want to print the first column with each comma separated value from the second.

```
Mary,Tom,David   cat,dog
Kevin   bird,rabbit
John    cat,bird
...
```

For each record in the second column ( eg `cat,dog` ) i want to split
record into array of [ cat, dog ] and cross print this against the
first column. giving output ( just for this line )

```
Mary,Tom,David   cat
Mary,Tom,David   dog
```

output for whole file should be be:

```
Mary,Tom,David   cat
Mary,Tom,David   dog
Kevin   bird
Kevin   rabbit
John    cat
John    bird
...
```

any suggestions if i want to use awk or sed?

Comment: Nothing in this question makes any sense.

Comment: @123 i need to make the file that way for later processing, just wonder if there will be some easier way using bash...or should i give more examples?

Comment: He mean that the question is a not clear not the interest you have to use such a format.  output does not show what your explanation specify. what are tab and comma separated for you ? comma and tab are generally column separator (CSV family)

Comment: So you need to convert `\t` to `\n` and `,` to `\t` or several spaces?

Comment: @NeronLeVelu, i hv changed the example to make it more friendly, hope that you can relate the input to the output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With awk

```
awk '{split($2,a,",");for(i in a)print $1"\t"a[i]}' file
```

Splits the second column on commas and then for each split value, print the first column and that value

Also in sed

```
sed ':1;s/\(\([^\n]*\t\)[^\n]*\),\{1,\}/\1\n\2/;t1' file
```

Comment: does split($2,a,",") mean split $2 into array a ?

Comment: @once yes, and with separator  `,`

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^((\S+\s+)[^,]+),/\1\n\2/;P;D' file
```

The process can be broken down to three commands: substitution, print and delete. Replace each `,` in the second field by a newline and the first field and the following spaces. Then print upto and including the newline and delete upto and including the newline and repeat. The key command is the `D` which will reinvoke the previous commands until the pattern space is entirely empty.

Comment: beautiful sed version of the answer!! but i am too stupid to understand even with your explanation

Comment: may i ask about S, s and P ..?

Comment: very nice use of `P` and `D`

Comment: @once `\S` is non space, `\s` space, `P` print first line, `D` delete first line (of current buffer)

Comment: @once `\s` matches whitespace and is a synonym for `[[:space:]]`, `\S` matches non-whitespace and is a synonymn for `[^[:space:]]`. An example of the uses of `N, P and D` see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#uniq).

Answer (score 1):

**process.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

while read col_one col_two; do
  IFS=, read -a explode <<< "$col_two";
  for val in "${explode[@]}"; do
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$col_one" "$val";
  done;
done <"$1";
```

with input.txt as

```
Mary,Tom,David   cat,dog
Kevin   bird,rabbit
John    cat,bird
```

**output**

```
$ ./process.sh input.txt 
Mary,Tom,David  cat
Mary,Tom,David  dog
Kevin   bird
Kevin   rabbit
John    cat
John    bird
```

Comment: explode is just the array name im reading it into ( reminds me of php function explode which is functionally similar to this bash script )

Answer (score 1):

with awk

```
awk '{split($2, aEl, ","); for (Eli in aEl) print $1 "\t" aEl[ Eli]}' YourFile
```

with sed

```
sed 'H;s/.*//;x
:cycle
   s/\(\n\)\([^[:cntrl:]]*[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)\([^[:cntrl:]]*\),\([^,]*\)/\1\2\3\1\2\4/;t cycle
s/.//' YourFile
```

Comment: there's another sed answer below/(above), it works perfect but i cant understand