# Separate 2nd column of comma separated list to new rows, inherit value in 1st column per new row

Tags: perl, awk, sed, replace

I have a tab-separated file like this:

```
ID1 blue
ID2 yellow,blue
ID3 green,yellow,red
ID4 red
1D5 red,purple
```

For the second column, I need to separate out the comma list, each color on its own row, and for every new row, I need to retain the ID#.

I was thinking of using sed to replace each comma with a new line, but then not sure how to add the associated ID back. Awk or perl? After much searching, I can't find the answer...

Final results will have no commas and look like this:

Final result:

```
ID1 blue
ID2 yellow
ID2 blue
ID3 green
ID3 yellow
ID3 red
ID4 red
1D5 red
1D5 purple
```

Any help very much appreciated.
This question is very similar to [Bash turning single comma-separated column into multi-line string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33408762/bash-turning-single-comma-separated-column-into-multi-line-string), but my column 1 is always a single value whereas the similar question has multiple values separated by a comma in col 1. I was unable to find my solution by reviewing the similar question. Hoping that this question is distinct enough to remain on this site and hopefully help others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'[\t,]' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1, $i}' file
ID1 blue
ID2 yellow
ID2 blue
ID3 green
ID3 yellow
ID3 red
ID4 red
1D5 red
1D5 purple
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Ed!

Answer (score 0):

This simple `awk` program should do it:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{ n=split($2,arr,","); for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print $1,arr[i] }' file
ID1 blue
ID2 yellow
ID2 blue
ID3 green
ID3 yellow
ID3 red
ID4 red
1D5 red
1D5 purple
```

We split the line into fields on tab (`\t`), and then for each line split the second field on commas (`,`) with [`split()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-split_0028_0029-function). Finally we iterate over all elements in the array `arr` and print one line per the (first field, array element) pair.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was tagged with various utility/glue languages, including Perl, so **this answer describes solutions using the Perl programming language**.

**Here is a Perl one-liner solution:**

```
perl -lF/\\t/ -e 'print "$F[0] $_" for split /,/, $F[1]' test.txt
```

Given a tab-delimited file as described in the question this produces the following output:

```
ID1 blue
ID2 yellow
ID2 blue
ID3 green
ID3 yellow
ID3 red
ID4 red
1D5 red
1D5 purple
```

This works approximately the same as the following **full Perl script:**

```
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    next unless length;
    my ($id, $colors) = split /\t/, $_;
    print "$id $_\n" foreach split /,/, $colors;
}
```

In these solutions I used `\t` to split on tabs, though the sample data you provided seemed instead to be space delimited, not specifically tab delimited.  If it is the case that your data is actually simply "whitespace" delimited, change `\t` to `\s+`.

**Here's how the one-liner works:**

`-l` sets auto-chomp for input, and auto-newline for output.  The `-F` switch implicitly sets `-a` (which means auto-split into `@F`), and `-n` (which means iterate over the input files passed on the command line).

The `-F/\\t/` means auto-split on the `/\t/` regexp, or in other words, on tab characters, populating `@F` with the results. (You could change `\\t` to `\\s+` if your data is more generally whitespace delimited.)

Therefore, for each line of input, `$F[0]` will contain the `IDx` field, and `$F[1]` will contain colors such as `yellow,blue`.

The `-e` command line switch means to evaluate the following code, and because we have `-n` implicit in `-F` we iterate over the file and execute the code once per line of the input files.

And the code we pass in is:

```
print "$F[0] $_" foreach split /,/, $F[1]
```

Which means that per line of the file, for each item in the color list, print the ID (stored in `$F[0]`) followed by the color (stored in `$_`).

We derive the colors individually by splitting `$F[1]`, which might contain `yellow,blue` on the comma, and populating `$_` for each color (using the `foreach` loop).

**Describing the script version:**

`while(<>) {...}` reads one line at a time from the files set on the command line (or from STDIN), and for each line populates `$_`.

**Relevant Documentation:**

Every full-installation of Perl ships with the `perldoc` command, which may be invoked with the name of a piece of Perl's documentation to read.

See the following:

- `perldoc perlrun` -- An explanation of Perl's command-line switches.
- `perldoc perlintro` -- A brief introduction to Perl.
- `perldoc perlre` -- A deep-end overview of Perl's regular expressions.
- `perldoc -f split` -- An explanation of how Perl's `split` function works.
- `perldoc perlsyn` -- A description of Perl's control structures such as `foreach` loops.
- `perldoc perlop` -- An overview of Perl's operators, including `<>`.

Furthermore, if your data is more complex than shown, using constructs such as quoting and escaping of delimiters, you should probably prefer the `Text::CSV` CPAN module for parsing the TSV / CSV file.

Comment: Thank you for all the details, DavidO!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^((\S+\s+)[^,]+),/\1\n\2/;P;D' file
```

Replace each `,` by a newline followed by the key and its whitespace (tab).

Answer (score 0):

Following awk may also help you in same.

```
awk '{gsub(/,/,RS $1"&");gsub(/,/," ")} 1'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

***gsub(/,/,RS $1"&"):*** Using awk's global substitute utility to substitute each comma in a line with `RS`(new line) $1(first field of that line) "&" denotes comma here(denotes variable/regex which we mention to be substituted).

***gsub(/,/," "):*** Again using global substitute utility to `awk`, so above `gsub` will make Input_file to look as follows.

```
ID1 blue
ID2 yellow
ID2,blue
ID3 green
ID3,yellow
ID3,red
ID4 red
1D5 red
1D5,purple
```

which is not our OP's output, so again globally substituting comma with simple space so get the correct output as follows.

```
ID1 blue
ID2 yellow
ID2 blue
ID3 green
ID3 yellow
ID3 red
ID4 red
1D5 red
1D5 purple
```